# Replacing given characters to new ones before a defined parameter in gsub function

Tags: r

I am not so qualified in R and I am struggling with a problem. I want to replace all the existing underscores which are before "S11" pattern, with the dashes "(-)".  S11 is just a number and it is variable in my table such as S29, S30. Here is the code that I am using and failing:

```
foo <- c("H2_2months_S11_L001_R1_001_(paired)_trimmed_(paired)_contig_940_[cov=11]_", "H2_2months_with_acetate_S101_L001_R1_001_(paired)_trimmed_(paired)_contig_940_[cov=11]_", "Formate_3months_S99_L001_R1_001_(paired)_trimmed_(paired)_contig_940_[cov=11]_")
Sample <- gsub(pattern="*(_S)", replacement="-", x=foo)
```

Getting: 
[1] "H2_2months-11_L001_R1_001_(paired)*trimmed*(paired)_contig_940_[cov=11]_"
[2] "H2_2months_with_acetate-101_L001_R1_001_(paired)*trimmed*(paired)_contig_940_[cov=11]_"
[3] "Formate_3months-99_L001_R1_001_(paired)*trimmed*(paired)_contig_940_[cov=11]_"

I also don't want `"_S"` to be deleted and replaced. I use `"_S[0-9]"` as a matching criteria and before `"_S"`, the underscores should be changed to `"-"`.

Also please recommend me a good website that I can learn those "codes or signs" using in this function. Thanks in advance.

Expected output: 
[1] "H2-2months-S11_L001_R1_001_(paired)*trimmed*(paired)_contig_940_[cov=11]_"
[2] "H2-2months-with-acetate-S101_L001_R1_001_(paired)*trimmed*(paired)_contig_940_[cov=11]_"
[3] "Formate-3months-S99_L001_R1_001_(paired)*trimmed*(paired)_contig_940_[cov=11]_"

Comment: Can you please add the expected output to your example? Should all the `"_"` be changed before the match or just the one before the `S11`?

Comment: Maybe try `stringr::str_replace()`, i.e. `str_replace(foo, '_S', '-S')`

Comment: All of the underscores before _S11 or any other "_S" should be changed to "-".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

Basically we divide the job in two parts, first match (`"_(S[0-9+])"`), then we split the resulting string at `"-"`, then we use `gsub` to fix all the `"_"` we find.

```
foo <- c("H2_2months_S123_L001_R1_001_(paired)_trimmed_(paired)_contig_940_[cov=11]_")
foo <- gsub(pattern="_(S[0-9+])", replacement="-\\1", x=foo)
#foo
#[1] "H2_2months-S123_L001_R1_001_(paired)_trimmed_(paired)_contig_940_[cov=11]_"
```

Then we split:

```
split <- unlist(strsplit(foo, "-")) # split using the new "-"
#split
#[1] "H2_2months"                                                     
#[2] "S123_L001_R1_001_(paired)_trimmed_(paired)_contig_940_[cov=11]_"
```

Now we can use simple `gsub` on everything except the last element in `split`.

```
split_1 <- split[-length(split)] # fix all the "_" before the match (exclude the last)
split_1 <- gsub("_", "-", split_1)
```

Then we `paste` the results:

```
paste0(split_1, "-", split[length(split)]) # paste back together
#[1] "H2-2months-S123_L001_R1_001_(paired)_trimmed_(paired)_contig_940_[cov=11]_"
```

---

Here in a function and with another example:

```
foo <- c("H2_2months_abc_456_S123_L001_R1_001")

my_foo <- function(s) {
  s <- gsub(pattern="_(S[0-9+])", replacement="-\\1", x=s)
  split <- unlist(strsplit(s, "-"))

  split_1 <- split[-length(split)]
  split_1 <- gsub("_", "-", split_1)

  paste0(split_1, "-", split[length(split)])
}

my_foo(foo)
#[1] "H2-2months-abc-456-S123_L001_R1_001"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I checked it and your solution is working for the given example. However, if I increased my input, it is not working. See the new example:
foo <- c("H2_2months_S123_L001_R1_001_(paired)_trimmed_(paired)_contig_940_[cov=11]_", "H2_2months_S1233_L001_R1_001_(paired)_trimmed_(paired)_contig_940_[cov=11]_351_566_+")

Comment: `unlist(lapply(foo, my_foo))` should do the trick. You should update your question with all the information that would help us understand better your problem. This solution may be slow if you have lots of strings.

Comment: Thanks Rlave,

with the unlist function, it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

This will match the "_S11" and save S11 to the group. Then replace this with a "-" followed by the captured group "S11".

```
Sample <- gsub("_(S[0-9+])", "-\\1", foo)
```

Excellent place to learn more regex: https://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html

Excellent place to test regex with explanations of the matching: https://regexr.com/

Edit: Thanks RLave, didn't realise it could be any digits after the S. Updated answer.

Comment: A more general solution is `"_(S[0-9+])"`

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the answers. However, I ran the code and it didn't change the first underscore. I have a table and there are a lot of underscores before "_(S[0-9+])" pattern.

Comment: @ÖmerCoskun I found this wording ambiguous until you updated the post with the expected result -  "I want to change all the underscores to dashes before S11". Consider rewording? Solution posted by RLave looks excellent I would follow this.